# Can statsd handle negative timings?

Tags: statsd

I am currently planning to use statsd to track performance difference between two procedures.

This means that we will see negative timings.

Is statsd able to handle negative timings?

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the documentation](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/metric_types.md) and [code](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/stats.js) I see nothing that *forbids* negative timings. You might have problems with timer histograms, since there

> a lower limit of 0 is assumed

However I strongly suggest using separate timers for both procedures, sending them to Graphite and using the [diffSeries](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.diffSeries) function.